# In which file monero is getting this "last_reward" and "last_timestamp" and how it is calculating that?

Tags: daemon, transaction-data, block-explorer, block-reward, database

In which file is Monero getting this "last_reward" and "last_timestamp" and how it is calculating that?

[Get stats](https://localmonero.co/blocks/api/get_stats)

Answer (score 1):

They don't need to "calculate" it, or obtain from a "file". There are a few ways to obtain but they probably use [get_last_block_header](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_last_block_header) from the daemon RPC interface.